# Is an ID column always necessary?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have created a table name `customers` with the columns:

```
Id,
CustomerId,
CustomerName,
Phone,
Address
```

In my scenario `CustomerId` is the primary key but the values in `CustomerId` are not in order.

I see many people who use an auto incremented '`Id`' as primary key, but in my case it will not be it and it will have no use whatsoever.

Is an '`Id`' column (Auto incremented) necessary in each and every table?

Comment: Do some research before posting, IDs are the most powerfull tool a RDBMS has, it hels you build faster queries and many others things. Usually the ID is also a PRIMARY KEY , read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186460/why-use-primary-keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CustomerId` is the PK, so it is also unique, in that case another unique ID generated by the system is not needed to create a unique row id. You may still want to create it for performance reason: a small datatype can store more index on the same index page, and that mean a faster search time. In that case you can create a `CLUSTERED UNIQUE INDEX` on the `ID` row and a `NON CLUSTERED PRIMARY KEY` on the `CustomerID` column if the `ID` have a smaller data type.

The order of the data in the table is a non-problem, never thing that a table is ordered on it's own, it is not. The data is ordered as the result of an ORDER BY clause in the query.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I understand what u said. I wan to explain one more thing and need your suggestion. I have PK on CustomerId which will always unique but customerId which will insert by user will not be in order or it can be a random number, i mean some time she can insert 1015 sometime 3008 sometime 6658. It will not be in

Comment: Thanks i got an answer:- now i droped Id column and just keep CustomerId as primary key. This key/Customerid is choosen by end user randomly. Thanks for your help :).

Answer (score 1):

The Id column (Auto increment or not) is usually used to differentiate the rows between them. In other words in many cases it can be used as a Primary Key.

It can also be used as a Foreign key to other tables, if you want to have relationships between them and construct inner joins etc.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading good, but some where your are wrong in terms of 2 column one is auto-increment and second is primary.

Generally and as per database creation standard or say normalized form of database, you must create a auto increment-id with primary-key column which is used as a reference of another table.

So no need of 2 column, only use one column with appropriate name and functionality / role. Never create extra column which you never use.

Here is good article for your basic understand about primary-key.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp

This links shows why we need primary key:-

**The Primary Key constraint is a convention to indicate that the declared column (or list of columns) constitutes a key.** (very good article) refer below link.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/376d565a-f16d-4ae4-afeb-ef2ef78dc4af/why-do-we-need-primary-key-in-a-database?forum=transactsql

https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090905225547AAAK6Ul

Answer (score 1):

Since the `CustomerID` is your primary key, the ID column may be dropped. An autoincrement column is often used as "Surrogate Key" in cases where you don't have just a simple key (or you have none). So you can create an autoincrement column and set that one as your primary key, mainly because a Clustered Index is a must have on a table. Having a Heap Table may be considered a bad practice in almost any situation.

Answer (score 0):

You *think* it has no use, but it often *has*.

The `Id` field is used to retrieve a column on something that makes it unique. It could be any column (you could even use `Name` for it), but Id is a convention everybody uses.

That kind of column is called a 'Primary Key'. As the name says: it's the primary way to identify a row.

Example:

> What if both `PostalCode`, `HouseNumber` and `Country` make an `Address` row unique. How to retrieve of reference a specific row? Either by specifying the three columns in a query, or just use the `Id`. Also, If you change either of the three columns, your reference will become invalid. The `Id` always stays the same.